# How do I prevent iframe to create a new <div> instead of <br> on linebreak

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am currently trying to create a text editor on React. I noticed when I try to create a `<blockquote>` when I press enter, it creates a new `<blockquote>` instead of creating a `<br/>`. Therefore I noticed it creates a `<div>` every time I create a new line (press Enter).
How do I make my iframe create a `<br/>` instead of a new `<div>` every time I press enter?

My code looks something like this:

```
quoteReply = description => {
        var doc = document.getElementById('iframeBody').contentWindow.document;
        var quoteDescription = "<blockquote>" + description + "</blockquote><br/>"; //block quote wrapper
        doc.write(quoteDescription);
}

render(){
 return(
   //code
   <div onClick = {this.quoteReply.bind(this, this.state.description}>test</div>
   <iframe
       id = "iframeBody"
       ref={(input) => { this.nameInput = input; }} 
       title = "threadBody"
       className = "createThreadBodyText"
       name = "iframeBody"/>
   //code
  )
}
```

Comment: Do you need to create a text-editor from scratch? There are a lot of libraries that will make things a whole lot easier for you like [quill](https://github.com/quilljs/quill) and [slate](https://github.com/ianstormtaylor/slate)

Comment: @itsanewabstract I can use quill but they dont offer some customization that I want, and also its for learning purpose since I'm new to creating web applications

Comment: Ah, I see. There's also [draft.js](https://draftjs.org/) which is more customizable. It's great that you're doing it for practice, nothing wrong there. But if you're going to use it in production then a library is definitely recommended since there are a lot of weird issues between the different browsers that can take a long time to figure out

Comment: @itsanewabstract Ahh I see, thanks for the heads up! :)